# Count the number of Correct Answered from the database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

Here the output p is always zero despite of containing correct answer.

```
 DataTable dt = bllSco.GetAllScore(SubId, UserId);
    int n = dt.Rows.Count;

    int p = 0, m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string check = dt.Rows[i]["remark"].ToString();
        if (check == "Correct")
        {
            p = p + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            m = m + 1;
        }
    }

    lblTotal.Text = n.ToString();
    lblCorrect.Text = p.ToString();
    lblIncorrect.Text = m.ToString();
```

Comment: Maybe `check` is not `Correct`? Did you debug your code check your values?

Comment: In debug mode what is the value of check?  No way check == "Correct" if p = zero.

Comment: check is Correct as well as Incorrect

Answer (score 0):

you should use sql code like this:

```
select count(1) FROM  table where col='Correct';
```

and then `fetch` result as `array`, and `arr[0]` is number that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

And you get count of that column records for more information use [w3schools count function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)